# React Native n OSX can't load app by simulators and terminal MAC

Tags: ios, node.js, react-native

I follow exactly the steps of creating React native apps 
and use

```
cd AwesomeProject
react-native run-ios
```

http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

When it comes to execution, 
The terminal always shows

```
Bundling `index.ios.js`  [development, non-minified, hmr disabled]  ░░░░░░░░░░░░
░░░░  0.0% (0/1)
```

After for a minute of loading, the IOS Simulator turns out this message
My npm version is 5.4.0 , react-native-cli :  2.0.1 , OSX Sierra 10.12.6. 
Checking status of port 8081,  react native package is running. I am not sure why this happen . Would you help me figure out this ?

[image: After for a minute of loading, the IOS Simulator turns out this message]

When executing "react-native start"

[image]

Comment: Did you try running `npm start` ?

Comment: same graph as above. hangs. I don't know what is going on

Comment: I have got this in info.plist ....

Comment: `<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
 <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
 <dict>
  <key>localhost</key>
  <dict>
   <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
   <true/>
  </dict>
 </dict>
</dict>` Put this in info.plist

Comment: @RajuGujarati are you run same WIFI mac os and iPhone ? I think you need to set same WiFi and after that run it

Comment: I use same wifi for MAC OS  and IOS. I am not sure whether I have to deploy this . I use iOS simulator by calling react-native run-ios